# Hiding output when saving into variable

Tags: r, printing

I would like to hide printed output when saving output of my own function.

```
f2 <- function(x) {
  cat("x + 5 = ", x + 5)
  invisible(x + 5)
}
f2(1)       # prints
a <- f2(1)  # also prints
```

In other words I would like to make my function print

```
x + 5 = 6
```

when calling `f2(1)` but in case of calling `a <- f2(1)` I dont want to show any printed output. Is there any easy way how to do that?

Comment: Does it have to be automatically? You could use a 'print_output' argument in your function definition, and an if-statement to check. What larger problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You could do this by returning an object that prints itself in the format that you desire.

Comment: Well, I would prefer some elegant way how to do that automatically but if there is no other chance I would use a 'print_output' argument as you suggested.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I'm not really sure how to implement this. Please, could you post an easy example? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a class system for this.  Here's a simple S3 example:

```
f2 <- function(x) {
          names(x) <- paste(x, "+ 5")
          class(x) <- c(class(x), 'foo')
          x + 5
       }

print.foo <- function(x) { cat(names(x), "=", x)}
```

In practice:

```
> x <- 3
> f2(x)
3 + 5 = 8
> y <- f2(x)
>
```

Note that the `print.foo` function does not handle vectors of length > 1 gracefully.  That could be fixed, if desired.